# How to create a lifecycle listener for an application deployed to WebSphere Application Server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

I have an application EAR deployed to WebSphere. How can I create a life cycle listener for the application that should invoke a one-time initialization code every time the application is launched?
I need to have something similar to WebLogic Server's classes `weblogic.application.ApplicationLifeCyleListener` and `weblogic.application.ApplicationLifecycleEvent`.

Answer (score 6):

EJB 3.1 specification added *singleton session beans* which may be used for application initialization in a portable, vendor-independent way.

Quoting from [Developing Singleton Session Beans](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tejb_ssb.html) , the following example illustrates a singleton session bean with startup initialization using `@Startup` annotation:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ConfigurationBean implements Configuration {
    @PostConstruct
    public void initialize() {
         // 1. Create the database table if it does not exist.
         // 2. Initialize settings from the database table.
         // 3. Load a cache.
         // 4. Initiate asynchronous work (for example, work to a messaging queue or to
         //    calls to asynchronous session bean methods.
    }

   // ...
}
```

If you are using EJB 3.1, which is part of Java EE 6 spec, this is the standard way of application initialization. WebSphere 8 and 8.5 support this specification level.

If you are using an older version of WebSphere or specification and you don't feel like upgrading, you may then use [Startup Beans](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/asyncbns/tasks/tasb_confstb.html), a WebSphere extension used for this purpose in previous versions.

Also +1 to Udo's answer.

Comment: There is a good article to show many ways to do this including above : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21412991

Comment: @yongsungyoon Nice link. Describes both methods. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a lifecycle listener for websphere. However you can create a dummy servlet that is initialized on startup.

```
<servlet>
  <display-name>YourServlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.example.YourServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/YourServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You don't need to call that servlet. It will load itself.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Java EE [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)?