# Application Server and Spring context loading

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, websphere

WebSphere Application Server has the below comment in one of their documentation. I have the application context at the ear level and use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` which is a subclass of `AbstractApplicationContext`. This is however not recommended. What are my options? What lifecycle hooks I can leverage at the ear level? Also, please include any gotchas or lessons learned.

> The following scenarios are examples of Spring Framework scenarios to
>   avoid:
>
> registerShutdownHook
>
> Avoid using the Spring Framework AbstractApplicationContext class and
>   its subclasses. These classes include the public method
>   registerShutdownHook, which creates a thread and registers it with the
>   Java virtual machine (JVM) to run at shutdown to close the application
>   context. As an alternative, an application can use the lifecycle
>   notices that it receives from the application server container to call
>   the close method explicitly on the application context.

Comment: Why not use the WebApplication context by wiring it up in your web.xml? That i believe is a better way to go with you web app.

Comment: Where do you create your `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`?

Comment: @dinukadev becauze i've ear with multiple wars that share the common services

Comment: @ShyJ in a singleton class's static initializer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [Singleton Session Bean](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Fae%2Ftejb_ssb.html) (in case of WebSphere 8+) or [Startup Beans](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Fasyncbns%2Ftasks%2Ftasb_confstb.html) (for older Websphere version) as it is described in a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867743/how-to-create-a-lifecycle-listener-for-an-application-deployed-to-websphere-appl).

For `Singleton Session Beans` you can create a method annotated with `@PreDestroy` which will [close](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#close()) the [AbstractApplicationContext](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html).

For `Startup Beans` you can do the same in the `stop()` method.